# Sending email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

I want to send an email from my site's email "info@mysitename.com".
But there is an error and the email don't send.
here in my code and error :

```
public void SendMail(string Subject, string To, string Body)
{
    SmtpClient MyMail = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage MyMsg = new MailMessage();
    MyMail.Host = "info@sitename.com";
    MyMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
    MyMsg.Subject = Subject;
    MyMsg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    MyMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    MyMsg.From = new MailAddress("info@sitename.com", "myname");
    MyMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    MyMsg.Body = Body;
    MyMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    NetworkCredential MyCredentials = new NetworkCredential("info@sitename", "pass");
    MyMail.Credentials = MyCredentials;
    MyMail.Send(MyMsg);
}
```

This is the error:
[image: error message]

Comment: Did you check the Status and Response properties of the exception like it told you to?

Comment: Can you please include the error message as text?

Comment: I doubt that "info@sitename.com" is a valid name for an SMTP Host

Comment: this is the error :

An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Failure sending mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the SmtpClient Host property is used for.

This line of code here is wrong...

```
MyMail.Host = "info@sitename.com";
```

`MyMail.Host` should point to your SMTP server - you're trying to set it to the FROM address.

You are already setting the FROM address in your `MailMessage` object, int he line shown below...

```
MyMsg.From = new MailAddress("info@sitename.com", "myname");
```

So, just to give you an example, I might have a server at the IP 10.1.0.5 and it runs an SMTP server on port 25.  You would set your `MyMail.Host = "10.1.0.5"`, or even better just set it in the constructor like this...

```
SmtpClient MyMail = new SmtpClient("10.1.0.5", 25);
```

Now, this is just an example - I don't know if / where you might have an SMTP server set up.  But if you don't have an SMTP server set up, that's something you're missing.  If you do have it set up, the Host property should be its IP or domain name.

Comment: how can i setup the SMTP server ?!!

Comment: That is a research project you're going to have to undertake.  Suffice it to say that there's a plethora of options, ranging from the built-in SMTP Server that Windows Server OS's offer, to paid 3rd party software, to open source options.  It's a bit off-topic for this forum.  Usually if you work for a company that has an System Engineering / IT department, they will set it up for you.  It's not really a programming related task - once you have a working SMTP server though, all you should have to do to your code is to properly point your SmtpClient at it.

Comment: This might be helpful if you want to use IIS as your SMTP Server...  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: TNX. I Notice that SMTP server is setup. 
in "MyMail.Host" i write the domain name.
now there is not any error . but the email isn't send